# Alfresco Search with a direct URL Parameter

Tags: url, search, web, alfresco

We have an existing web application that has configurable URLs with parameters for an easy integration of other systems. For example: I can easy generate a clickable URL like https://external-system/&query=Invoice_123456.

We also run Alfresco for document storage and an archive of PDFs. If I go to Alfresco Share and search for "Invoice_123456", I can see the documents that I was looking for.

Is there something like an URL for searching the Alfresco Repo globally for content by using a GET or POST parameter? For example: "https://alfresco.local/share/search/query=Invoice_123456"

We're using Alfresco 5.0.b currently.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you using? (The answer differs based on version - there's been a lot of work on "cleaner" rest APIs in 5.1 for example)

Comment: We're currently using 5.0.b. I'll add this info to the question above. Thanks.

Comment: Go to http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/ or http://localhost:8080/alfresco/services/ (I can't seem to remember this, EVER), and you'll find all your web scripts there. You will find the one you need, no doubt.

Comment: Also, check this out: https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully I'm not oversimplifying this, but yes... basically you just need to include a "searchTerm" hash parameter... for example:

/share/page/dp/ws/faceted-search#searchTerm=Invoice_123456

It is also possible to add in further URL hash parameters for scope (e.g. repository wide, within sites, within a specific site), sort field/direction and any facet filters that should be applied.

The simplest way to achieve this it to perform the search you want and then copy/paste the URL from the browser (this is why I'm wondering if I'm missing some nuance from the question!?)

Comment: I tried that first, copied the search URL, replaced the searchTerm and built the link, but I only got a page without results from Alfresco.

I just tried it again and saw, that the other software while it builds the link, it seems to truncate the link after the "#" which means that the searchTermin isn't anymore. And so I don't get results. That's not an Alfresco problem.

All other possibilities like ?searchTerm= and so on don't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the slingshot API

This is the definition of the webscript :

```
GET /alfresco/s/slingshot/search?term={term?}&tag={tag?}&site={site?}&container={container?}&sort={sort?}&query={query?}&repo={repo?}
```

Since I don't exactly have your case, here is an example for a document search by the name property :

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/slingshot/search?query={"prop_cm_name":"Invoice_123456","datatype":"cm:content"}
```

You can find more information in the description of this webscript at this url of your local alfresco :

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/script/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get
```

Now, if you want a html output instead of a JSON one, you cant create your own template **search.get.html.ftl** and create the view you need.
(you have many ways to do this ([inside the war, or in the extension folder](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/concepts/ws-component-place.html))

Then you can call your webscript with the **format** parameter :

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/slingshot/search?query={"prop_cm_name":"Invoice_123456","datatype":"cm:content"}&format=html
```

Comment: Thanks - searching works, but I get a JSON response. I'd need just the results in the Alfresco Share.

Comment: Ok, I didn'd had this in mind. I've updated my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for updating, I'll take a look at it.